# Array no se actualiza

Tags: nodejs

Estoy trabajando con NodeJS, creo un `Array` y luego hago una consulta a mi base de datos. Cuando obtengo resultados, hago `push` para añadir elementos al arreglo, sin embargo cuando quiero imprimir los elementos no hay nada.

```
function sendMessageToUser(req, res) {
    var devicesTokenNotification = new Array();
    req.getConnection(function(err,connection){
        var query = connection.query('SELECT usuario_id, PERIOD_DIFF(DATE_FORMAT(created, "%Y%m"), DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y%m")) as meses FROM documento', [], function(err, rows){
            if(err)
                console.log("Error Selecting : %s ",err );

            if (rows.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    if (rows[i].meses > 7){
                        var queryUsuarios = connection.query('SELECT deviceToken from usuario where id = ?', [rows[i].usuario_id], function(err, row){
                            if(err)
                                console.log("Error Selecting : %s ",err );

                            devicesTokenNotification.push(row[0].deviceToken);
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            for (var cont = 0; cont < devicesTokenNotification.length; cont++) {
                console.log(devicesTokenNotification[cont]);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Sin embargo, si aplico el mismo `for` pero dentro de la consulta `queryUsuarios` si imprime los valores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este problema es bastante común, y es por la asincronía, lo que te está pasando básicamente es que al momento de la ejecución que llega al for que recorre tu devicesTokenNotification esta variable aún no tiene nada pusheado, esto es porque las consultas a la base son más lentas que la ejecución de javascript, además de que la ejecución no espera a que el for termine.

Aquí puedes ver maneras de evitarlo: https://carlosazaustre.es/manejando-la-asincronia-en-javascript/

Lo que debes hacer es esperar que termine ese for.

saludos!